# Need to create a JUnit test case in eclipse using the WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, cxf

I am trying to create a JUnit test cases for a web service but I'm facing a problem to do it.

At present I'm having 2 WSDL's with me.

I need to create 2 different projects for 2 WSDL's.

For one WSDL I'm able to create Junit TC's, because after importing that WSDL using CXF it automatically created 2 packages which had all the required details in it.

But for the other WSDL it is creating only one package. So I'm not getting how to create JUnit TC's for this WSDL.

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue.

Note: First WSDL is having only one soap action but secont WSDL is having 4 soap actions.

Comment: Technically speaking, you are not creating _unit_ tests if you are testing a SOAP web service, but rather you are creating _integration_ tests.

Comment: If you have CXF stubs for the second WSDL, then why can't you create some testing code?

Comment: But for the second WSDL it created only one package. it has not created the second package which would have all the details about that particular web service @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Then this isn't a unit test problem, it's a WSDL/CXF problem.

Comment: Show us your wsdl. And you can write unit tests, if you want to, without them being integration tests. See this approach: https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf